# Issues with intersection code for scene primitives

Tags: python

I'm encountering a puzzling issue with my ray tracing code when trying to simplify the intersection calculations for different scene primitives. The following code works as intended:

```
distances, hit_orientation = zip(*[(sphere_intersect(s, ray['origin'], ray['dir']) if isinstance(s, list) and s[0] == 'sphere' else 
                                   plane_intersect(s, ray['origin'], ray['dir']) if isinstance(s, list) and s[0] == 'plane' else 
                                   s.intersect(ray['origin'], ray['dir']) if not isinstance(s, list) else (None, None)) for s in Sc['scene_primitives']])
```

However, when attempting to achieve the same functionality in a more straightforward manner, the code fails:

```
distances = hit_orientation = []
for s in Sc['scene_primitives']:
    if isinstance(s, list):
        if s[0] == 'sphere':
            a = sphere_intersect(s, ray['origin'], ray['dir'])
        elif s[0] == 'plane':
            a = plane_intersect(s, ray['origin'], ray['dir'])
    else:
        a = s.intersect(ray['origin'], ray['dir'])
    distances.append(a[0])
    hit_orientation.append(a[1])
```

This is not normal i guess.

Comment: Fails how, exactly?

Comment: `distances` and `hit_orientation` are not the same.

Comment: The problem is `distances = hit_orientation = []`.  That creates two references to ONE list.  So, both appends will modify that one list.  Separate that into two statements and it will all be fine.

Comment: OMG thank you so much what a stupid mistake i did. Write an answer if you want.

Comment: Well, this is basically a typo. and we aren't supposed to provide answers for typos.  We provide a comment and vote to close.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok thanks but quick question: Why `distances = hit_orientation = [].copy()`  is not woking too?

Comment: @IDi because it's still two references to the same list, this is meaningless - there's no point in copying list literal. Rightmost expression is evaluated first, so you construct a copy of an empty list (surprisingly, anther empty list), and then assign it (same to both) variables. You need two lists - if you want this one-line, you can do `first, second = [], []`, though this style is questionable

Comment: @STerliakov Appreciate your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Right. It's the `a = b...` part that causes the problem.